# Wordpress 3.0 multisite internal server error

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory, addon-domain

I have WordPress (3.0) multisite installed (and correctly configured according to the WordPress ['Create A Network'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_3:_Allow_Multisite) tutorial) in the root of an add-on domain with two sites created using the subdirectory method of network install.

My site structure is as follows:
ADDON DOMAIN: http:/example.com/ (wordpress install location)
SITE 2: http:/example.com/site2/
SITE 3: http:/example.com/site3/

I have been getting random Internal Server Errors every now and then which disappear after waiting a few minutes and visiting each site again.

I have a suspicion that the cause of this could be something to do with either the .htaccess file (in the root directory of the add-on domain), or a redirect issue to do with the wp-config.php file. All generated mod_rewrite rules were added to my .htaccess file above /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */. HostGator is my host.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal server errors tend to be caused by using the wrong character encoding when editing the .htaccess file.

And it also sounds like you might be adding .htaccess rewrite rules to wp-config.php, which you don't do. The `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` line appears in the default wp-config.php file and not in .htaccess.

Rediects and mod_rewrites only go in .htaccess files, where you will find the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comments.

.htaccess and wp-config.php are two different files for two different purposes.